# When comparing the values of words in python, why would "Nick" be greater than "George"?

Tags: python, ascii, character

I am studying for an upcoming assignment and trying to figure out what the following program prints:

```
d = ["Bob", "Tom", "George", "Susan", "Mary"]

n = raw_input("Enter a name: ") # assume user enters Robert

for name in d :
    if name < n :
        print name

print

size = len( d )

i = 0

while i < (size - 1) :

    if d[i] > d[i+1] :
        temp = d[i]
        d[i] = d[i+1]
        d[i+1] = temp 
    else :
        d[i+1] = "Nick"

    i += 1
for name in d :
print name
```

I am very confused because when I run the program it returns:

```
Enter a name: Robert
Bob
George
Mary

Bob
George
Nick
Mary
Nick
```

I am clearly confused as to how to calculate the value of words. I thought you assigned the ascii value to the individual letters and added them together to get the value, but using that method would not get these results.
could someone please help me understand?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

They are in dictionary order, so the first letter is the only thing that matters if it isn't the same.

To do what you want, use

```
value=sum([ord(x) for x in name])
```

Comment: update (just saw it was homework) - also known as **Lexicographic order**!